# (keras) input a tensor and a index, get the tensor i want

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My Input is like a (3,3,2) array and a (3,3) array:

```
img = np.array([[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]],
                [[4,4],[5,5],[6,6]],
                [[7,7],[8,8],[9,9]]])

idx = np.array([[1,0,0],
                [0,0,1],
                [1,1,0]])
```

My ideal output should be:

```
[[1 1]
 [6 6]
 [7 7]
 [8 8]]
```

I want to do this by a custom layer:

1. make a layer:

```
def extract_layer(data, idx):

    idx = tf.where(idx)
    data = tf.gather_nd(data,idx)
    data = tf.reshape(data,[-1,2])

    return data
```

2. make into model:

```
input_data = kl.Input(shape=(3,3,2))
input_idxs = kl.Input(shape=(3,3))
extraction = kl.Lambda(lambda x:extract_layer(*x),name='extraction')([input_data,input_idxs])
```

I can build the model , and i can see the keras summary of the model,
the output is

```
model = Model(inputs=([input_data,input_idxs]), outputs=extraction)
model.summary()

...
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 3, 3, 2) 
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 3, 3) 
extraction (Lambda)             (None, 2)
Total params: 0
...
```

but when i start to predict like :

```
'i have already made the two inputs into (1,3,3,2) and (1,3,3) shape'
result = model.predict(x=([img,idx]))
```

it gets error:

```
'ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,2) into shape (1,2)'
```

i think the tensor of shape(4,2) is the value i want
but i don't know why keras broadcast it to (1,2)

is there anyone who can help me ??

thanks very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `extract_layer()` function, the `data` is two dims tensor. But `model.predict` is supposed to return results with an extra batch dim. Just expand the dim when return `data` in `extract_layer()` can fix this error.

```py
def extract_layer(data, idx):

    idx = tf.where(idx)
    data = tf.gather_nd(data,idx)
    data = tf.reshape(data,[-1,2])

    return tf.expand_dims(data, axis=0)
```

**Note**: Since the results returned by `tf.gather_nd` might have different length, I think the batch size would only be 1. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: i'll try more about the batch thing

Comment: @newbie_engineer Is your batch size larger than 1？

Comment: i've tried make a data with (2,3,3,2) and (2,3,3) , and change something in the "def extract_layer(data, idx)" , make the output shape as [-1, 4, 2], it can work perfect !!!

Comment: the second data , is the same as the first one~~ i think it works when there are surely four "1" in the idx, so every single output is a [4,2] shape tensor~~~~

Comment: @newbie_engineer Cool! Upvote or accept will be appreciated.